# Combinations of sets raised to the power of a prime modulus: $\binom{p^{\alpha}-1}k \equiv (-1)^k \pmod p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

This is a problem out of the text Introduction to the Theory of Numbers by Niven, Zuckerman, and Montogmery and I am having quite a bit of trouble with it.  I tried to prove it directly, but that didn't work.  The question is:

> Let $p$ be a prime and $\alpha$ a positive integer.
>   Show that $\binom{p^{\alpha}-1}k \equiv (-1)^k \pmod p$ for $ 0 \leq k \leq p^\alpha -1$.

If relevant, I did prove that ${{p^{\alpha}}\choose k} \equiv 0 \pmod p$ for $ 0 < k < p^\alpha $ but I can't seem to incorporate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$${p^a-1\choose k}={(p^a-1)(p^a-2)\cdot\dots\cdot(p^a-k)\over(1)(2)\cdot\dots\cdot(k)}\equiv{(-1)(-2)\cdot\dots\cdot(-k)\over(1)(2)\cdot\dots\cdot(k)}=(-1)^k$$ where the congruence is modulo $p$.

Comment: The hint is good but somewhat cryptic. At the very least I'd mention having to cancel powers of $p$ from each $p^a - i$ and the corresponding $i$. (Fortunately, each $p^a - i$ has exactly the same power of $p$ in it as the corresponding $i$, so that no factors of $p$ are left after the cancellations.)