# $\binom{p^a-1}{k}\equiv(-1)^k\pmod{p}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, factorial

> Show that $\binom{p^a-1}{k}\equiv(-1)^k\pmod{p}$ for $0\le k\le p^{a}-1$.

Solution: $\binom{p^a-1}{k}=\frac{(p^a-1)(p^a-2)\cdots(p^a-k)}{k!}$.

Idea: Then power of $p$ in $k!$ must be less than the power of $p$ in Numerator.          ----(**)

Then i can directly write 
$p^a-1\equiv-1\pmod{p}$,$p^a-2\equiv-2\pmod{p}\cdots$ and $p^a-k\equiv-k\pmod{p}$.

Then, we have: $\binom{p^a-1}{k}\equiv(-1)^k\pmod{p}$.

Is my idea correct? If yes, how should I proceed to prove (**) statement.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cbinom%7Bp%5Ea-1%7D%7Bk%7D%5Cequiv(-1)%5Ek%5Cpmod%7Bp%7D%24&p=1) for several earlier threads studying this problem.

Comment: Very sorry about picking a wrong version among the duplicates. See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/961938/11619).

Comment: In addition to searching your question, please refrain from having an all MathJax title.

Comment: I'll just add some links to the above comments: [How to search on this site?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29265) and [Guidelines for good use of $\rm\LaTeX$ in question titles](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9687).

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thankyou for the kind feedback.